# WCF Client/Server config mismatches

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-config, streaming

I have written a WCF service that uploads a file to the server. It is configured to stream the file, because they may be fairly large. I set transferMode = Streamed in my web.config and set various config size settings to fairly large-ish sizes.

This work fine for my test client. I had to set the client configurations manually to have transferMode= Streamed -- by default when I included the service reference it had set it to Buffered.

But the guy who is consuming my service is complaining about having to do that manual step. He keeps telling me something is wrong with my service and I need to fix it. I don't see anything that I can "do" about the settings not propagating to the client. And it work fine if he uses the config settings I sent him.

Is there something I should be doing? And if not is there some kind of proof I can offer this person to convince him my service is not broken? Anyone have a link to an article explaining this?

Comment: how is he generating the wsdl/client? (i.e. is he using a service reference or do you give him a dll?)

Comment: I've published the WCF on an IIS Server and he uses a service reference. Also, when I include a service reference in my test client and then update the reference the client configurations don't get overwritten, so these manual settings only need to be set once. But he claims that when he updates the service reference it overwrites his config settings.

Comment: is there a reason he can't use svcutil to generate the reference? i find using svcutil is much more stable than a service reference. i mean, it's wcf, what does this guy think, that he doesn't have to do anything?

Answer (score 1):

If the guy's platform, who is consuming your service, is .Net, then you can create client library with correct configuration, which consumes your service and give him to use it.

There are well known article [WCF the Manual Way… the Right Way](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0809101)

Comment: I read the article and it's interesting, though it looks like it might be a challenge for me to implement this. Basically it looks like a lot more work for me to implement. I don't think I should have to re-write a working service just because this guy can't update his own application config. Thanks for the link. I may try this in a future service.

Comment: Yes it requires more time to implement, but it's really better way.

Comment: When I build the next service from scratch I will try this way. Since I seem to have convinced the other dev that he has to set the config manually I'm going to save myself a re-write this time. Thanks for the response though. I appreciate it.